# When are indecomposable projective modules finitely generated?

Tags: ring-theory, representation-theory, projective-module, finitely-generated

What conditions to you need to put on your ring to guarantee that the indecomposable projective modules are all finitely generated?

Edit: I was hoping there was some general result for this. If your ring is Krull-Remack-Schmidt then the indecomposable projective modules are generated by an idempotent in your ring so they are finitely generated.

I don't know of any rings in which they are not finitely generated, but I fear I'm not creative enough (if it's true for all rings that would be great too though).

Comment: If your ring is local or a PID, then projective means free so your condition follows

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I realize that sometimes for questions of this sort, it is difficult to think of context. Might I suggest you list some sufficient conditions you already know, and perhaps some counterexamples you know of where an indecomposable is not finitely generated?  This would alleviate concerns about context. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. What I really want to do is show that the projective indecomposable modules of the skew group algebra of the complex power series ring and an automorphism group is finitely generated, but I thought there might be a general result. I tried looking it up, but couldn't really find anything. Neither have I made any noteworthy progress on the problem myself. If there is little known about the problem, I might just try a different approach.